# How to present array of objects like array of another objects

Tags: java

I have

```
class ForeighObject {...}
void someMethod(Object[]) {...}
```

and

```
ForeighObject[] fobjects = SomeStorage.getObjects();
```

I can manipulate only with fobjects, so I cant change neither structure of `ForeighObject` nor `someMethod`. How could override `ForeighObject.toString` (for example) to pass it to the `someMethod` without copying elements? Can I create some adapter class that could "present" `ForeighObject` to override only one method?

Comment: You say that you cannot change the structure of `ForeighObject`, however can you at least see the source code?  If so it might help creating a subclass which is able to initialise itself from a `ForeighObject` instance.  Alternatively, does the `ForeighObject` class have a constructor which takes another `ForeighObject` as an argument in order to clone it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what you mean but I guessing that `someMethod` makes a call to `toString` on the elements of the array of objects its given.

If this is the case then you can wrap each of the elements of `fobjects` using a wrapped subclass of `ForeighObject` which contains the expected `toString` method.

e.g.

```
//Subclass which wraps a ForeighObject instance..
class ForeighObjectWrapper extends ForeighObject {
    ForeighObject wrapped;
    ForeighObjectWrapper(ForeighObject toWrap){
       super(/* get values from toWrap */);
        this.wrapped = toWrap;
    }
    //Add the custom behaviour..
    public String toString(){
         return "Some custom behaviour: " + wrapped.toString();
    }
}

ForeighObject[] fobjects = SomeStorage.getObjects();  //as before..
ForeighObject[] fobjectsWrapped = new ForeighObject[fobjects.length];
for(ForeighObject ob : fObjects){
    fobjectsWrapped.add(new ForeighObjectWrapper(ob));
}

//then call someMethod on fobjectsWrapped instead of fobjects..
someMethod(fobjectsWrapped); //will invoke custom behaviour..
```

Note that if the someMethod also relies on the behaviour of other methods/properties of the wrapped instance then you'll need to override these methods so that they work as expected..

Comment: Yeah, I solved it in that way (except I used composition). But I want to avoid this: 

    `for(ForeighObject ob : fObjects){
        fobjectsWrapped.add(new ForeighObjectWrapper(ob));
    }`